# Where is the class list_iterator defined?

Tags: python, python-3.x, iterator

I would like to see the definition of the class `list_iterator`. When I try to display its definition with the function `help` I get an error. Is there a module that I have to import in order to access to its help?

More precisely, I would to know how to get a reference to the object iterable that the iterator iterates. For example:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5]
it = iter(l)
print(type(it))   # this prints: list_iterator
# how to get a reference to l using it
```

I am pretty sure the object `it` has a reference to the object `l`. This example proves it:

```
import sys
l = [1,2,3,4]
print(sys.getrefcount(l))   # prints 2
it = iter(l)
print(sys.getrefcount(l))   # prints 3
```

So the third reference surely came from `it`

Comment: I don't think `it` would necessarily *have* a reference to `l`. As it exits at the C level, it could have direct access to the array in which the data is stored, bypassing the `list` object. (I'm not sure `list_iterator` is even defined by Python; it may be an implementation detail of CPython.)

Comment: @chepner `ìt` does have a reference to `l`. See my update.

Comment: Source is there : https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3c87a667bb367ace1de6bd1577fdb4f66947da52/Objects/listobject.c#L3075

Comment: How hacky / nonportable a solution is good enough? `it.__reduce__()[1][0]` does it in current CPython, but it's not something I'd want to rely on.

Comment: `print(it.__class__.__dict__)` will show you what you can use for the object itself.

Comment: I should have been clearer: I don't think `it` *exposes* its reference at the language level (Mark's comment nonwithstanding; I've never really been clear just *what* `__reduce__` does).

Comment: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/listobject.c#L3121 shows the C-level reference to C object representing the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does garbage collection's [`get_referents`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/gc.html#gc.get_referents) do it for you?

```
import gc

l = [1,2,3,4,5]
it = iter(l)

refs = gc.get_referents(it)  # looks like: [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
assert l in refs  # True
assert l == refs[0]  # True
```

EDIT: It should be noted that the reference to `l` disappears when `it` is exhausted and raises `StopIteration`. So when you finish iterating over `it`, the reference-check above fails. This can be a feature or a bug depending on your use case but you should be aware of it.

```
# Exhaust the iterator
for x in it:
    pass

refs = gc.get_referents(it)
assert l not in refs  # No more reference to l
assert not refs  # No more reference to anything actually
```

Comment: Clever. Very interesting idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Very clever.

Comment: In general, peeking into an object's referents with `get_referents` is a dangerous thing to do. Most Python C code is written assuming you can't access the references `get_referents` exposes, and accessing those references anyway can lead to memory corruption and arbitrarily weird results.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica hmmm I didn't know peeking into references could cause memory issues. I knew it wasn't great practice but didn't know it was dangerous. Do you have any links about that? I'm not doubting -just curious.

Comment: @BrianJoseph: Read-only access probably won't do anything too bad, although it's theoretically unsafe. Anything beyond that can get very nasty very fast, though. [Here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48717893/modifying-class-dict-when-shadowed-by-a-property/48718098#48718098).